# A word for someone who's excessively interested in sex but rarely partakes it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or succinct way of describing someone who's interested in lewd stories, dirty jokes and the like, but does not necessarily have the chance to have sex on account of their unattractiveness. To be clear, these people are probably not trying to hide their sexual interest; they might openly ask for dirty jokes or flirt inexpertly, for example.

Context:

> Curiously, whether the protagonist is described as a chaste suitor of a single lover or an industrious womanizer correlates greatly with the number of ____ in the tavern.

I considered the word "lecher", but the word implies that the individual in question actually succeeds as getting laid, whereas the sort of people I'm trying to describe are not the kind that succeed much in that regard.

Comment: I would say that your word **lecher** is appropriate: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lecherous) says of **lecherous**: *Having or showing excessive or offensive sexual desire.* I tend to think of a lecher as someone who drools but does not partake.

Comment: I'd go for: sexually frustrated. If the gentleman is middle-aged or more advanced in years.. he's simply *a dirty old man*.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult. “Voyeur” has some of the mental attributes of such people but is not appropriate because it involves seeing sexual activity for vicarious pleasure rather than imagining it for sexual arousal or titillation.

A search for synonyms was fruitless and all I am left with is the aural memories from youth of:

*A dirty mind*, *a dirty old man*, *sleazebag*, *sleazeball*

“You are just a dirty mind.” “Rotten joke, you dirty old man!”

Strangely, Google ngram finds no occurrences of “a dirty mind” as a noun phrase.

If we descend to offensive slang, a *wanker* has overtones of low morals, stupidity and masturbation, which itself implies inability to get the real thing. So it fits your specification but may be offensive.

Perhaps *dirty old men* in the tavern* is the best I can offer.

> = an older man who has an unpleasantly strong interest in sex
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dirty-old-man)

Answer (score 0):

[Incel](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/incel/), a slang short for *in*voluntarily *cel*ibate.

> Short for involuntary celibacy, incel refers to an internet subculture of men who blame women for the fact that they are not having sex.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/incel/)

Comment: this would be appropriate for a modern context, but I'm intending to write something more formal sounding that wouldn't break the tone of a fantasy fiction

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to a

***[voyeur](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/voyeur)*** noun, disapproving:

> a person who gets sexual pleasure from secretly watching other people in sexual situations, or (more generally) a person who watches other people's private lives.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

If we're assuming they're interested in sex with women, "[skirt-chaser](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/skirt+chaser)" might work because it implies a lot of attempts, but says nothing about the number of successes. As a bonus, you can joke about how they would be "[the dog that caught the car](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+dog+that+caught+the+car) if any of the ladies in the area dropped their standards low enough.

> Curiously, whether the protagonist is described as a chaste suitor of a single lover or an industrious womanizer correlates greatly with the number of (bootless/inept) **skirt-chasers** in the tavern.

Answer (score -1):

Such a person might be described as a "tease".

Lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tease) a tease as follows:

> A person who tempts someone sexually with no intention of satisfying the desire aroused.

and provides example sentences such as:

> I wasn't trying to be a tease: I simply realized I wasn't comfortable going all the way with him.